# Is the construction "which [noun] [rest of sentence]" proper as a means of introducing a dependent clause, rather than "which [rest of sentence]"?

Tags: grammar

In other words, would this construction be proper? And if so, is there a name for it?

> The court then turned to negligence, which issue it easily resolved.

(As opposed to ". . ., which it easily resolved.")

Aha. I missed this when I first looked at MW. I think it's the third definition under the first section: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/which

Comment: It's overly formal, and therefore common in and about legal prose.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Formal, but I don't think overly. Not to the extent of being stilted.

Comment: If you hafta ask about its propriety, it's overly formal.

Comment: OK, I get the desire to speak glibly about this, but there are different registers people do use to communicate. Sometimes people wear suits, sometimes swim trunks. A time and a place for everything.

Comment: The court then turned to register, which issue it did not easily resolve.

Comment: I'd only specify *issue* if the **which** could refer to other things. Otherwise, ick, talking down to the reader, OCD.

Answer (score 1):

> *The court then turned to negligence,* [*which issue it easily resolved*].

It's called a relative construction, one where in this case the bracketed element is a non-defining relative clause.

Here, "which" is a determinative determining the head "issue"; it combines with it to form the relativised element "which issue", whose interpretation is given by the antecedent, "negligence".

The gloss is: "the court then turned to *x*; the court easily resolved *x*."

Examples like this are rare and formal, and bordering on the archaic.